# Undeploy automatically before stopping debug session in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, glassfish, application-server

I would like to configure IntelliJ IDEA to undeploy the application when I attempt to stop the debug session. I mean to the undeploy the artifact and then stop debug session with a single click.

I need to do this because if I stop the application server many times the database doesn't allow more connections and I have to restart the DB.

Is that possible?

INFO: I'm running Glassfish Server 4 from IntelliJ integration.

Comment: Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108426

Comment: @CrazyCoder The problem is different but the solution would be the same or similar. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ IDEA has Startup/Connection option where we can set up Startup/Shutdown scripts according to application server.
I hope your app server has some scripting tools to do so